# I have a diagram and i need to reproduce it, but it gives me a lot of problems

Tags: java, oop

[image]

I'm new to Java and i have to do this diagram, but i have a lot of problems, in Company i have the following:

```
  public class Company {
    private String name;

    public Company (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In Share:

```
 public class Share  {
    private double value;
    private Company company;

    public Share(double value, Company company) {
        this.value = value;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

And in Portofolio i have:

```
    public class Portofolio {
   private int noShares;
   Share shares[];
   private int numberOfShares = 0;

    public Portofolio(int noShares) {
        this.noShares = noShares;
    }

    public void addShare(Share newShares) {
        shares[numberOfShares++] = newShares;
        newShares.setValue(numberOfShares);
    }

    public int getNoShares() {
        return noShares;
    }

    public Share[] getShares() {
        return shares;
    }
}
```

So i solved the error i had earlier, but i still don't know how to make the method computeSum so it gives me the value from the image.

Comment: Congrats on nailing pretty much everything. You need to initialize your array to an empty array of the desired size inside the constructor of Portfolio.

Comment: You have to change Share shares[]; to Share[] shares;
and then add to your constructer: shares = new Share[]();

Comment: I followed an example from a method with addAccount who did exactly the same and it worked for some reason.

Comment: @Triims both `Share shares[];` and `Share[] shares;` are valid and it is the same.

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't knew that

Comment: @Triims `shares = new Share[]();` is also invalid java syntax. I think you should make sure you are posting correct comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize and expand your Share array.

```
public void addShare(Share newShare) {

    if (shares == null) {
        shares = new Share[0];
    }
    else {
        Share[] newShares = new Share[numberOfShares+1];
        System.arraycopy(shares, 0, newShares, 0, numberOfShares);
        shares = newShares;
    }

    shares[numberOfShares++] = newShare;
    newShare.setValue(value);
}
```

If you are allowed to, you should use a List instead of an Array, that's easier to use.

Comment: And i need the method computeSum who is double , how can i add all the values stored, like in the image i posted, that was bothers me. Also i solved the error problem, it was because i didnt declared the length of the array, but i still have no idea how to add all shares.

Comment: You still have no idea how to add all shares, so you seem to have problems to understand my answer. Where is your exact problem?

Comment: About `compueteSum()`, please give it a try by yourself.

Comment: I tried your method, but when i try to get the value for example for the first share the value is 1.0 instead of 1200.0. Also i tried to use a for loop for compute, but i have problems with the values now

Comment: You have to learn to debug. You set a wrong value with `setValue()`.

Comment: So, newShare.setValue(numberOfShares); is not correct? Also yes i need to learn i m programming in Java just for about 2 weeks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223690/discussion-between-milgo-and-moonzen-boss).